sed command unable to replace variable value which is more than space
I would appreciate it if someone could assist me in finding a solution to the problem below.
I can successfully replace the TAG value (when we have only one value) in my configuration file.
[root@test c]# TAG=123
[root@test work]# sed 's/tagExpression: "tag_expression"/tagExpression: "'$TAG'"/g' wdioJenkins.conf.js >test.js
[root@test work]# grep tagExpression test.js
        tagExpression: "123",

The following errors are being generated when I declare multiple values for the TAG variable. I made multiple attempts, but I couldn't achieve this.
[root@test work]# TAG="@SFX-TC-4930 or @SFX-TC-4931 or @SFX-TC-3898"
[root@test work]# echo $TAG
@SFX-TC-4930 or @SFX-TC-4931 or @SFX-TC-3898
[root@test work]# sed 's/tagExpression: "tag_expression"/tagExpression: "'$TAG'"/g' wdioJenkins.conf.js >test.js
sed: -e expression #1, char 62: unterminated `s' command


I had to guess what your formatting was supposed to look like. Going forward, please notice that you get a preview below the question pane whilst you are composing. Probably also read the editing help.

As an aside, don't be root whilst trying to figure things out.

Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

I’m voting to close this question because the OP didn't run their code through http://shellcheck.net as the [tag:bash] tag instructed. Had they done so, shellcheck would have told them about the problem.

You need to double quote your shell variable to prevent splitting.
sed 's/tagExpression: "tag_expression"/tagExpression: "'"$TAG"'"/g'

There are a lot of quotes in your command, but parsing it is not that difficult. The single quote always pairs with the next single quote, regardless of what characters are in between. So everything from the opening quote up to the : after tagExpression is a whole string. The '"/g' is another string, and it should be clear now that the $TAG in the middle is unquoted and subject to globbing and splitting. In your particular case, due to splitting, sed will see six arguments:

s/tagExpression: "tag_expression"/tagExpression: @SFX-TC-4930
or
@SFX-TC-4931
or
@SFX-TC-3898"/g
wdioJenkins.conf.js

The first of them is taken as the command and you can see clearly the s command is missing a closing slash. The rest will be parsed as file names and it doesn't make sense anyway except for the last one. sed is just erroring out on the first failure. If the first argument happen to be a valid command, you will instead see sed complaining about file or not found.
In general, use https://shellcheck.net to find out issues in your Bash script as bash indicates.

If you enable debug mode (set -xv) you can see what sed sees:
$ set -xv
$ sed 's/tagExpression: "tag_expression"/tagExpression: "'$TAG'"/g' wdioJenkins.conf.js 
+ sed 's/tagExpression: "tag_expression"/tagExpression: "@SFX-TC-4930' or @SFX-TC-4931 or '@SFX-TC-3898"/g' wdioJenkins.conf.js
sed: -e expression #1, char 62: unterminated `s' command

Notice sed sees an incomplete s command followed by 4 other strings and then the file name:
sed 's/tagExpression: "tag_expression"/tagExpression: "@SFX-TC-4930' or @SFX-TC-4931 or '@SFX-TC-3898"/g' wdioJenkins.conf.js
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

As Weijun has mentioned one solution would be to wrap $TAG in double quotes so the white space in $TAG is considered as part of the data thus giving you a complete sed / s command:
$ sed 's/tagExpression: "tag_expression"/tagExpression: "'"$TAG"'"/g' wdioJenkins.conf.js
+ sed 's/tagExpression: "tag_expression"/tagExpression: "@SFX-TC-4930 or @SFX-TC-4931 or @SFX-TC-3898"/g' wdioJenkins.conf.js
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Keep in mind a sed script can be wrapped in double quotes thus allowing OS variable substitutions.  For processing literal double quotes you can escape them with a backslash.
Setup:
$ cat wdioJenkins.conf.js
line1
tagExpression: "tag_expression"
line3

Modifying OP's current sed call:
$ sed "s/tagExpression: \"tag_expression\"/tagExpression: \"$TAG\"/g" wdioJenkins.conf.js 
line1
tagExpression: "@SFX-TC-4930 or @SFX-TC-4931 or @SFX-TC-3898"
line3

